# Material UI- Divider not in Middle in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Title says it all - my divider is not lying in the middle of my text. My current result looks like this:

[image]

But I want my divider to be in the middle likeso (see red line)

[image]

What's weird is that the material ui documentation demonstrates that this is a default behavior but for some reason it is not the case for me.

My code is as follows:

```
<Divider textAlign="center" variant="inset"><Typography variant="h3">About</Typography></Divider>
```

Comment: it is working on the codesandbox.you can check out on this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-189q3n?file=/test.js:159-177)

Comment: Hmm yeah, it works there but it doesn't seem to work on my browser. I even tried removing all the components around the divider but that didn't change anything

Comment: maybe you have other css values on the parents elements that the child elements inherit and would cause this problem

Answer (score 5):

Wrapping your Divider component in a div or a Box should do the trick:

```
<div>
     <Divider>About</Divider>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and what i did to solve it is to give the typography a display flex, align and justifyContent to the center and also setting the width and the height to 100%

```js
  <Divider
        textAlign="center"
        sx={{
          border: "1px solid #E6E6E"
        }}
      >
        <Typography
          variant="h3"
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            alignItems: "center",
            
          }}
        >
          About
        </Typography>
      </Divider>
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work, thank you for your input though